# Searching names with inconsistent formatting

Tags: vba, excel

I built a sub that iterates over a sheet of business transactions for the day and addresses and attaches PDF receipts for our customers.  Some customers work for the same firm, but are treated as different entities so they each receive their own email receipts.  Folks from this particular firm are only identifiable as a team by their email handle, which is how I have been matching what receipts go to which email handles for which individuals.

**Problem:**
The problem I've encountered is that in the contacts master list (holds all of the contact information) the names are listed as first name then last name (I.E. John Snow) and on the occasion one of the external systems that information is pulled from lists the names as Last name then first name (Snow John), which isn't found by my current code.  I know I could probably use `InStr` but to me that's a bit sloppy and the information contained in these receipts are extremely confidential.  I'm struggling to come up with an consistent way to find the name regardless in a neat and eloquent way.

Possible solution I thought of was to split the names and store them into an array and then compare the different index places, but that seems inefficient.  Any thoughts?

**Current Code that is insufficient** *Note: This is only a small function from the main routine*

```
Private Function IsEmpSameFirm(empName As String, firmEmail As String, firmName As String) As Boolean
    'Finds separate employee email and compares to current email to find if same distribution
    Dim empFinder As Range, firmFinder As Range
    Dim columnCounter As Long

    columnCounter = 1

    While firmFinder Is Nothing

        Set firmFinder = contactsMaster.Columns(columnCounter).Find(firmName)

        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
    Wend

    Set empFinder = contactsMaster.Rows(firmFinder.Row).Find(empName)

    If empFinder Is Nothing Then

        IsEmpSameFirm = False

    ElseIf empFinder.Offset(0, 1).Value = firmEmail Then

        IsEmpSameFirm = True

    Else

        IsEmpSameFirm = False

    End If


End Function
```

Comment: How does one know that `Snow John` is `lastname firstname`? How would the code know? What if there are like names like [Alexander Frank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_Alexander) or [Frank Alexander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Frank)?

Comment: I would suppose that one could search the list for `John Snow` and if it isn't found, split it and reverse it to search for `Snow John`. If it still isn't found then flag it for manual intervention since sharing very confidential information is probably worse than relying on software for 100% accuracy.

Comment: The code wouldn't know.  That's my point.  So i'd have to think of a methodology to search again for a second time, but actually splitting, flipping, and searching again could eb a viable method to check once more.  All of these emails are checked by human eyes before they're sent; they're just assembled by code.

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer:** *It is not possible* 
**Middle answer:** This implies a reasoning: 
- You loop through your memories to recall which of the 2 gaven "Strings" is a name and which one is a last name. If you wish the PC to do the same, you'd need to "teach" it that -write a DataBase which contains every last name you know and if it's found there then it's a last name-
**Long Answer:** 
What I'd do is split the text in columns, do a filter for each one and then analyze them "manually", this function may help you to split the string

```
 Function RetriveText(InString As String, ChrToDivide, Position As Long)
 On Error GoTo Err01RetriveText 
 RetriveText = Trim(Split(InString, ChrToDivide)(Position - 1)) 
 If 1 = 2 Then '99 If error 
Err01RetriveText: RetriveText = "Position " & Position & " is not found in the  text " & InString 
 End If '99 If error 
 End Function
```

IE:
A1 =John Smith
 
B1 =RetriveText(A1," ",1) 'Result: John
C1 =RetriveText(A1," ",2) 'Result: Smith 
Edit: Just realized that you are trying to send by email, are they contacts in Outlook? If so, why not to check them there? Try this function

```
Public Function ResolveDisplayName(sFromName) As Boolean
'----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' Procedure : ResolveDisplayNameToSMTP
' Author    : Sue Mosher - updated by D.Bartrup-Cook to work in Excel late binding.
'-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim olApp As Object 'Outlook.Application
    Dim oRecip As Object 'Outlook.Recipient
    Dim oEU As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeUser
    Dim oEDL As Object 'Outlook.ExchangeDistributionList
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set oRecip = olApp.Session.CreateRecipient(sFromName)
    oRecip.Resolve
    If oRecip.Resolved Then
        ResolveDisplayName = True
    Else
        ResolveDisplayName = False
    End If
End Function
```